# Why Oozie need jobTracker and nameNode?

Tags: apache-spark, oozie-workflow

I am using Apache Oozie for scheduling some Apache Spark Application. I read more document about Oozie and create some example of schedule job. I realize that all of workflow contains jobTracker and nameNode property. Why Oozie need 2 of them. If I don't have jobTracker property (it point to yarn resource manager). What happend with this? Any one can explain this for me? Thanks!

Comment: Oozie runs jobs on Yarn, hence no Yarn => no Oozie.

Comment: Oozie is a pure Hadoop scheduler, but it was designed (by _Yahoo!_) to be able to schedule jobs on **multiple** clusters (because that's how _Yahoo!_ operates). That's why the `jobTracker` and `nameNode` params are explicit.

Comment: Can you provide me any document about that. Thanks!